# Scrapy pipeline extracting in the wrong csv format

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

My Hacker News spider outputs all the results on one line, instead of one each line, as it can be seen here.

[All on the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwQKf.png)

Here is my code.

```
import scrapy
import string
import urlparse
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class HnItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    score = scrapy.Field()  

class HnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hackernews'
    allowed_domains = ["news.ycombinator.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://news.ycombinator.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = response

        selector_list = response.xpath('.//table[@class="itemlist"]')


        for sel in selector_list:
            item = HnItem()


            item['title'] = sel.xpath('.//td[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('.//tr[@class="athing"]/td[3]/a/@href').extract()
            item['score'] = sel.xpath('.//td[@class="subtext"]/span/text()').extract()

            yield item
```

and my settings.py file

```
BOT_NAME = 'hnews'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['hnews.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'hnews.spiders'

USER_AGENT = 'hnews (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

FEED_URI = '/used/scrapy/hnews/%(name)s/%(time)s.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

I've tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943075/struggle-to-build-scrapy-pipeline-to-export-csv-file-in-the-right-format-any-he) among many other solutions but no luck so far. I'm still very new at this, so bear with me if possible.

Comment: What does it look like when you open the csv file in a text editor?

Comment: What's in your pipeline?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kf81aj6C

Comment: Please paste in pastie or pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your item pipeline is getting all the lists at once. For expample: The `item['title']` is getting a list of all the titles at once which is then transferred to the item pipeline and then written to the csv file directly.

The solution is to iterate over the list and yield it to the item pipeline one at a time. Here's a modified code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class HnItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    score = scrapy.Field()  

class HnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hackernews'
    allowed_domains = ["news.ycombinator.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://news.ycombinator.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = HnItem()
        title_list = sel.xpath('.//td[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()[:-2]
        link_list= sel.xpath('.//tr[@class="athing"]/td[3]/a/@href').extract()
        score_list = sel.xpath('.//td[@class="subtext"]/span/text()').extract()
        for x in range(0,len(title_list)):
            item['title'] = title_list[x]
            item['link'] = link_list[x]
            item['score'] = score_list[x]
            yield item
```

Comment: That worked! Fantastic! Thanks a lot, I've been stuck on it for 2 days now.