# Scrapy exports all results in one row in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, scrapy

I'm making a basic spider using Scrapy and want to store the data with SQLite. The spider is working fine and saves the data I want, but it writes all data on the same row in the database.

Here's my spider:

```
    def parse(self, response):

    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@class="class"]'):
        item = ScrapedItem()
        item['Name'] = sel.xpath('*/header/div//h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['Site'] = sel.xpath('*/header/div/a[1]/text()').extract()
        item['Category'] = sel.xpath('*/header/div/h6[3]/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

And here is my pipeline:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
from xyz import settings
from xyz import items
con = None

class Pipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupDBCon()
        self.createTables()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.storeInfoInDb(item)
        return item

def storeInfoInDb(self, item):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Table(\
            Name, \
            Site, \
            Category\
            ) \
        VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ? )", \
        ( \
            str(item.get('Name', '')),
            str(item.get('Site', '')),
            str(item.get('Category', ''))
        ))
        print item.get('Name', '')
        self.con.commit()

def setupDBCon(self):
    self.con = lite.connect('test.db')
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()

def __del__(self):
    self.closeDB()

def createTables(self):
    self.dropAgencyTable()
    self.createAgencyTable()

def createTable(self):
    self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \
        Name TEXT, \
        Site TEXT, \
        Category TEXT )")

def dropTable(self):
    self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Agency")

def closeDB(self):
    self.con.close()
```

How do I save my scraped data in one separate row per scraped item?

Comment: Please provide the link of the page you are trying to scrape. Also look a this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511252/scrapy-pipeline-extracting-in-the-wrong-csv-format/34517346#34517346

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rahul, problem solved!

Comment: Let me add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511252/scrapy-pipeline-extracting-in-the-wrong-csv-format/34517346#34517346) by me. The problem is your spider is extracting all the items and storing it in a list and the yielding it to the items pipeline. So the item pipeline is not getting the information one at a time. The solution for this is to use a loop and iterate over all the desired rows one by one.