# Scrapy Spider save to csv

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website and save the information and I have two issues at the moment.

For one, when I am using selenium to click buttons (in this case a load more results button) it is not clicking until the end and I can't seem to figure out why.

And the other issue is that it is not saving to a csv file in the parse_article function.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Southwestern"
    allowed_domains = ['www.reuters.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.reuters.com/search/news?blob=National+Health+Investors%2c+Inc.']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(
                "search-result-more-txt")
        #next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[1]')
        # maybe do it with this
        #button2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Super')]")
            try:
                next.click()

            # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except:
                break

        SET_SELECTOR = '.search-result-content'
        for articles in self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, SET_SELECTOR):
            item = {}
            # get the date
            item["date"] = articles.find_element_by_css_selector('h5').text
            # title
            item["title"] = articles.find_element_by_css_selector('h3 a').text

            item["link"] = articles.find_element_by_css_selector(
                'a').get_attribute('href')

            print(item["link"])

            yield scrapy.Request(url=item["link"], callback=self.parse_article, meta={'item': item})
        self.driver.close()

    def parse_article(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']

        texts = response.xpath(
            "//div[contains(@class, 'StandardArticleBody')]//text()").extract()
        if "National Health Investors" in texts:
            item = response.meta['item']
            row = [item["date"], item["title"], item["link"]]
            with open('Websites.csv', 'w') as outcsv:
                writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: In your `parse_article` method you always rewrite your `Websites.csv` file, you should append to it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to wait a bit after click so that data will be loaded. I suppose sometimes your script searches for a button before new data and a new button were displayed.

Try using implicit_wait or explicit_wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element
# (or elements) not immediately available.
driver.implicitly_wait(implicit_wait)

# An explicit wait is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further
# in the code.
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, <time in seconds>)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
```

2. 'w' is for writing only (an existing file with the same name will be erased). Try 'a' (appending) argument. Though I would recommend using pipelines: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955439/5372300)

Answer (score -1):

First issue looks like button hasn't appeared. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47252205/3029287) can aid you.

One more thing, try to close `driver` when Scrapy is shutting down. Probably [this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#module-scrapy.signals) can help you.

Second issue looks like you are going to do `open` and write many times and that is not good, since you will be overwriting existing contents. Even with 'a' flag e.g. `open(FILE_NAME, 'a')` this is not good practice in Scrapy.

Try to create `Item` populate it and then use `Pipelines` mechanism for saving items in CSV file. Something like [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file).

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But question, am I not closing the driver after the for loop  when I call `self.driver.close()`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just went a step further in case you keep adding more start URLs.