# How could I launch my scrapy script with PHP?

Tags: php, python, scrapy

this is for example my script ,i type "scrapy crawl quotes" in the shell to execute it , so how can i launch this command in php ?

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"
start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
        yield {
            'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
            'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
            'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the correct way to run php files in command line is

```
php file.php
```

If this is not what you are asking for please clarify.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('scrapy crawl quotes');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

This will run the terminal command in php.

[**Reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: thanks for the answer ,, so how i can define the path of the python script ?

Comment: You can always just do python /path/to/file/file.py in the shell_exec

Comment: @ZouhirSarrar If the python script is in the same location as phone script then no need to do file path. Also it will run the command as www-data user.

Comment: @ZouhirSarrar my answer also prints the outcome onto the screen in code format as you can see. If this helped I would appreciate an upvote or check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I give you what I use for my project

```
chdir('/Path_to_folder');
shell_exec('scrapy crawl yourSpider -a firstParam="'.$firstParam.'"' . ' -a secondParam="'.$secondParam.'"');
```

for more information

[**Chdir**](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.chdir.php)

[**shell_exec**](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: thank you for the answer , i tried ur script , but how can i print the output of the crawling in php ?

Comment: you want to print the items?

Comment: and there is the condition to execute " scrapy crawl myspider " in the main directory of the project ?

Comment: yes the items in a table for example

Comment: For your first question read the doc :) and for the second one, if you have no obligation to print your items, it's better to export your result to csv or json https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971406/4527978

Answer (score 0):

To execute an external program from PHP you want to use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

An example in your case would be:

```
<?php

exec('scrapy crawl quotes');
```

Be careful to consider the current working directory if the PHP is being executed by Apache or Nginx. You'll most likely need a full path to `scrapy` unless it's already in your `$PATH`.